# Proving the existence of two cycles sharing no edges in the Graph satsifying below conditions

Tags: graph-theory

In a party there are $10$ people. Total $14$ handshakes were made . Prove that there exists two different groups of some people(more than 3 each and one may be common in both) in which each person in the group is having handshake from two persons from that group.

> My idea was this for a general N vertices $N \geq5$ :

- Consider a graph of $N$ vertices and $N+4$ edges . If we can show that there exist two cycles sharing no edges then we are done most likely , but how do we show it ? I am not getting the idea for that

Comment: I don't think the original statement to be proven is actually true. You could have 5 people forming a complete graph (with 10 edges) and another 5 people forming a line graph or tree graph (with 4 edges). I don't see how these 10 people could contain two such groups. Or are the groups allowed to overlap? Are the two cycles allowed to share edges, but just not be identical?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis your graph does have two cycles of 3 sharing no edges in the completed one . Oh yes also i forgot mentioning there can be one person in common in both groups . In general my main problem is to solve the graph frame problem , i think thats always true